# Result of CONCAT function not showing the exact required result in first row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, concatenation

Here is my code:

```sql
SELECT
   usertype, CONCAT(start_station_name, 'to', end_station_name) AS Route, COUNT(*) as num_trips,
   ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS Duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY num_trips DESC 
Limit 10
```

the result is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0QQf.jpg) is shown.

Comment: make sure you filter out NULLs in stations if you dont want them. Else this is as expected.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. "This is not what I want" doesn't help much.

Comment: add space before and after to, as follow ' to '